# how to avoid AutoComplete in android app

Tags: android, autocomplete, keyboard

I have placed an edit box and in that box the user has to type his email id and when he clicks a button it must be send to network.

When the user starts typing his name it gives some suggestions above the default keypad of the device, if the user selects one among them a small **space** appears after the name that gets selected.

If it is to be the last name no problem but if he is to type anything next to the word it goes on with a space and it creates problem in getting return data from network.

how to disable the the word suggestions....

Comment: are you testing in on emulator or on device??

Comment: is ur app running on android device or emulator??

Comment: @Sujit - actually i want it to be disabled in my app alone.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **textNoSuggestions** value for the **`android:inputType`** attribute.

For example:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the input type to no suggestions. There is also an input type for email addresses. From 2.1 on, the input type can be set in the layout.